# What is the probability that a randomly chosen $x$ in $[0,\infty)$ is less than 1, if the probability density function on $[0,+∞)$ is given by ...

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, solution-verification

I want to make sure that I solved the next problem correctly:

What is the probability that a randomly chosen $x$ in $[0,+\infty)$  is less than 1, if the probability density function on $[0,+\infty)$ is given by:
$ρ(x)=\frac{r}{1+x^2}$
for some $r$.

This is what I did:

1. I make sure the PDF met the requirements, that is:
   $ρ(x) \geq 0$ and $\int_{D}ρ(x)dx = 1$
   Therefore, I solved: $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{r}{1+x^2}dx = r\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{\pi r}{2}$, therefore $r$ must equal $\frac{2}{\pi}$ for $ρ(x)$ to be a PDF.
2. I found the probability by integrating the new PDF over the domain $[0,1]$
   $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\frac{2}{\pi}dx = \frac{1}{2}$

I just want to make sure that my result is correct, any help would be appreciated :D
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes that looks fine to me. But please add $dx$ to your integrals, especially if there is more than one variable occurring.

Comment: @stange Thank you for your comment stange. Thanks for your help! :D